# stacking embeddings ELMO, BERT, FASTTEXT

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, text-classification

I'm trying to combine elmo,glove and bert embedding for text classification. First I started to concatinate elmo and glove, which is throwing error at concatinating. I adjusted the dimentionalities though it is not working. How to combine bert,elmo and glove embeddings?

Here is my code:

```py
elmo = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3").signatures["default"]
glove_file = "/content/drive/MyDrive/glove.6B.100d.txt"  

word2vec_output_file = "/content/drive/MyDrive/glove.6B.100d.txt.word2vec"
glove2word2vec(glove_file, word2vec_output_file)

glove_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_output_file)

def elmo_vectors(x):
    embeddings = elmo(tf.constant(x))["elmo"]
    # with tf.Session() as sess:
    #     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #     sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    return np.array( embeddings)


def glove_vectors(text):
    embeddings = [glove_model[word] for word in text if word in glove_model.vocab]
    # getkeys
    return np.array(embeddings)

# Example text data
texts = "This is the first sentence.", "This is another sentence."

# Preprocess the text data and generate ELMo embeddings and glove
elmo_embeddings = elmo_vectors(texts)
glove_embeddings = np.array([glove_vectors(text.split()) for text in texts])

#concatenating
combined_embeddings = np.concatenate((elmo_embeddings, glove_embedding), axis=1)
```

is throwing error at concatenating the elmo and glove. elmo has dimension [2,5,1024], and glove has [2,]

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-3baa51247f49> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 combined_embeddings = np.concatenate((elmo_embeddings, glove_embeddings), axis=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

I tried reshape(), resize, squeeze, np.expand_dims()